# How to pass shared_ptr to class with lower lifetime?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I'd like to optimize my code. I have one class that has a shared_ptr data member. In some methods of this class, I create objects that need to use this member (just to get information from the object pointed by shared_ptr). I know that lifetime of these created objects is lower than in my main class.
How to pass this pointer? I think another shared_ptrs is unnecessary (because I have a warranty that the object will exist). So what should get my created classes? Should they get raw pointer? Weak_ptr? Or the best solution is getting shared_ptr (and incrementing its reference counter)? What is the most standard solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In this case when you *know* the life-time of your shared resource will outlive those that you pass the pointer to the *correct* thing to do is pass a *reference* or a *raw pointer*:

```
void func(object* o)
{
    // do stuff with o
} 

// ...

std::shared_ptr<object> sp;

// ...

func(sp.get()); // pass raw pointer
```

The main reason for this is that the function can be useful no matter what kind of *smart pointer* is managing the resource. By accepting the *raw pointer* your function is able to accept objects from *shared pointers* as well as *unique pointers* and any other third party *smart pointer*.

There is no benefit to passing in the *smart pointer* unless the function needs to modify the *smart pointer* itself.

A good set of guidelines being produced by Bjarne Straustrup & Herb Sutter can be found here: [CppCoreGuidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md)

The rule about passing raw pointers (or references):
[F.7](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#f7-for-general-use-take-t-or-t-arguments-rather-than-smart-pointers)

> Passing a smart pointer transfers or shares ownership and should only be used when ownership semantics are intended. A function that does not manipulate lifetime should take raw pointers or references instead.
>
> Passing by smart pointer restricts the use of a function to callers that use smart pointers. A function that needs a widget should be able to accept any widget object, not just ones whose lifetimes are managed by a particular kind of smart pointer.

Answer (score 3):

When passing the `shared_ptr` into a function that will not store the resource, pass it by reference:

```
void foo(const shared_ptr<T>& ptr)
{
    // Basically just a pointer dereference
    std::cout << ptr->bar() << '\n';
}

int main()
{
   std::shared_ptr<T> ptr{std::make_shared<T>()};
   foo(ptr);
}
```

That won't increment the reference count, but that's fine — you're effectively treating it as a raw pointer (because you're just temporarily inspecting the pointee) but in a way that's safe because if you accidentally copy it then you'll get the reference count increment that can save your life. :)

However, if `foo` needs to store any sort of handle to this object, then you should pass in the `shared_ptr` by copy … or consider using `weak_ptr` so that you at least get some semblance of safety.

The above contrived example is so simple that I'd actually make it the following:

```
void foo(const T& ptr)
{
    std::cout << ptr.bar() << '\n';
}

int main()
{
   std::shared_ptr<T> ptr{std::make_shared<T>()};
   foo(*ptr.get());
}
```

Comment: Some minor typos there, depending on what you meant. Either dereference the `ptr.get()` return value when calling `foo`, or let `foo` take `const T*`.

Comment: @JohannGerell: Oh yes, single missing `*`. Thanks.

Comment: I usually just dereference the smartpointer directly to get at the dereferenced pointee :)