# unique_ptr and pointer by reference argument type

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I have code where I am trying to pass the underlying pointer of a unique_ptr in to a method accepting a pointer by reference:

```
unique_ptr<A> a;

func(a.get());
```

to call:

```
void func(A*& a){   // I am modifying what `a` points to in here

}
```

but I am getting compiler errors because `get()` is not returning what I expected was just the raw pointer. Is it possible to achieve what I am trying to do here?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: If you only want to modify what `a` points to and not the smart pointer then you should accept a *raw pointer* as a parameter, not a *raw pointer reference*: `void func(A* a);`: This link is about `shared_ptr` but same logic applies: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35543520/how-to-pass-shared-ptr-to-class-with-lower-lifetime/35543963#35543963

Answer (score 13):

No, and that's a good thing.

The problem is that `get()` returns an rvalue, not a reference to `unique_ptr`'s internal pointer. Therefore you can't modify it. If you could, you would completely mess up `unique_ptr`'s internal state.

Just pass a reference to the `unique_ptr` itself if you want to modify it.

Answer (score 4):

A function that takes a pointer by reference is strongly hinting that it may reallocate/delete the pointer in question. That means it is asking for ownership responsibilities. The only safe way to call such a function is to release the pointer from the unique pointer and (possibly) reacquire it after the call.

```
// a currently manages (owns) the pointer 
std::unique_ptr<A> a;

// release ownership of internal raw pointer
auto raw = a.release();

// call function (possibly modifying raw)
func(raw);

// (re)claim ownership of whatever func() returns
a.reset(raw);
```

But that can still be problematic if (say) the `unique_ptr` has a special *deleter* and the function doesn't re-allocate the object accordingly. Also if the function *deletes* the pointer without setting it to `nullptr` you will have a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an idea:

```
template<typename T> struct raw_from_ptr {
    raw_from_ptr(T& pointer) : _pointer(pointer), _raw_pointer(null_ptr) {}
    ~raw_from_ptr() {
        if (_raw_pointer != null_ptr)
            _pointer.reset(_raw_pointer);
    }
    raw_from_ptr(pointer_wrapper&& _other) : _pointer(_other._pointer) {
        std::swap(_raw_pointer, _other._raw_pointer);
    }
    operator typename T::pointer*() && { return &_raw_pointer; }
    operator typename T::pointer&() && { return _raw_pointer; }

private:
    T& _pointer;
    typename T::pointer _raw_pointer;
};

template<typename T> raw_from_ptr<T> get_raw_from_ptr(T& _pointer) {
    return raw_from_ptr<T>(_pointer);
}
```

Usage:

```
unique_ptr<A> a;
func(get_raw_from_ptr(a));
```